# How to switch to the laptop screen after using external monitors

Tags: display

My laptop was working with displays on two external monitors and laptop closed.
Now I'm away with just the laptop and the laptop screen is light but nothing on it. I can't click on control panel to fix then display settings. What can I do?

Comment: You should mention your operating system.

Comment: @Arjan I wasn't sure because the OP hasn't mentioned an OS and I wasn't sure what was meant by the laptop screen being light.

Comment: It' window 7 OS. dell Latitiude E6430.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your laptop still thinks it's connected to the external displays.

There is a shortcut key combination that you can use to change the presentation display mode. I have a feeling the presentation display mode is set to projector only.

If you hold the <kbd>windows</kbd> key and press <kbd>p</kbd>, you'll be able to switch between the different modes. Makes sure you wait a few seconds after pressing <kbd>p</kbd> to allow the switch to take affect.

If the above doesn't fix your issue, the gpu (integrated or discrete) may be at fault.

Comment: Yes it does look like it thinks it's still connected but this didn't work, nor the solution below.

Comment: Are you still able to use the laptop with the external monitors? If you are, you could connect the laptop to the monitors and try changing the presentation display mode from there.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to press and hold the <kbd>FN</kbd> button and look on your keys for a symbol like 2 squares (it's possible to be drawn with other color than the regular keys, perhaps blue) and press it. On a DELL notebook the combination is <kbd>FN</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd>.